# What could cause [UIImage imageWithData] to crash when it comes back

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uiimage, exc-bad-access

I have this code in one of my `NSManagedObjects`:

```
if (self.tempImageStorage) {
    return self.tempImageStorage;
} else if(self.imageData) {
    NSLog(@"%@ %d",self.imageData, self.imageData.length);
    self.tempImageStorage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    return self.tempImageStorage;
}
```

Occasionally, usually when I'm flipping through the images quickly, it will come back with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the 5th line (UIImage imageWithData line), and I can't po (printobject) self in the console, so I assume that the `NSMananagedObject` itself has been deallocated. What doesn't make sense is that it was able to reference self for the 2 ifs, and I even log the image data and its length just fine right before it.

How could the `NSManagedObject` be deallocated in during that period since this is all happening on the same thread (and it's the main thread)?

PS: I have Zombies enabled but it still doesn't let me po self.

Code that sets the image data:

```
- (void) processRequest:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request
{
    UIImage * orig = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];
    CGSize targetSize = isPad()?CGSizeMake(446,150):CGSizeMake(320, 108);
    CGRect fourPanelSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 336);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([orig CGImage], fourPanelSize);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

    if (bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone || bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaLast) {
        bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    }

    CGContextRef bitmap;
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetSize.width, targetSize.height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);    

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(1, 1, targetSize.width-2, targetSize.height-2), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    NSData * thumbData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
    NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(orig);

    //Post notification on main thread since it will be updating the UI
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        self.tempImageThumbStorage = newImage;
        self.imageThumbnailData = thumbData;
        self.tempImageStorage = orig;
        self.imageData = imageData;

        [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate saveContext];

        NSMutableDictionary * userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        [userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"status"];
        [userInfo setObject:self forKey:@"comic"];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PCRLoadMediahNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
        strongSelf = nil;
    }];

}
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code about how you are handling the changing of images. Also, your `self.imageData` may not be formatted correctly, and is causing `imageWithData` to return some garbage value.

Comment: I've added the code that sets the imagedata. If the imagedata was in the wrong format or incorrect though, it would be a different error, I'm pretty sure. Also, considering that this is happening on the main thread and imageData can only be set on the main thread, I'm not really sure how it would be corrupted. The weird part is that "self" and "imageData" is ok the line above, but then when you come back from the call "self" is no longer a good object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was saving the context too often which was causing the imageData not to be saved to disk properly, and causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with the same problem when I was parsing image from internet. So then when I was recreating image in app I got crash like this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData] -> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =2 0x...)
```

So my problem was that I have not synchronized this action with main app thread, that is why my app was crashing. The strangest part: that simulators works perfectly while real device crashes.

To make synchronization I have added this action:

- (void) GetImage:(NSData*)imgData number:(int)i
  {

  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
      @synchronized (imgData) {
          //UIImage* img2=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
          NSLog(@"picture number %d",i);
          uiimager_array[i] =[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
      }
  }];

}

After that I am calling in my loop this void function which is now not leads app to crash. 
Hops that helps